# Deleting one of a pair of values based on the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, select

Say I have the values:

```
Reference      Class  Timestamp
XXHAG70        11     2013-05-07 14:29:59.820
XXHAG70        11     2013-05-07 14:33:19.780
XXHAG70        17     2013-05-07 14:30:19.930
XXHAG70        17     2013-05-07 14:33:44.690
PAF7010        06     2008-11-06 10:25:07.140
PAF7010        06     2009-02-27 12:56:11.420
```

Each class has a duplicate value and therefore is paired. I want to select just the oldest timestamp for each class in each reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the oldest for each class/reference, use `MIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Reference, Class, MIN(Timestamp)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Reference, Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the row_number function.

```
SELECT  Reference ,
        Class ,
        Timestamp
FROM    ( SELECT    Reference ,
                    Class ,
                    Timestamp ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Reference, Class ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rnum
          FROM      MyTable
        ) A
WHERE   rnum = 1;
```

Comment: Should be `partition by Reference, Class`, and you'd want to keep the oldest row, so try `where rnum > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MIN`:

```
SELECT MIN(TimeStamp)
FROM YourTable
WHERE Class IN (SELECT DISTINCT Class From YourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would delete all but the oldest row per `(reference, class)`:

```
delete  from t1
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by reference, class 
                    order by Timestamp desc) rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) t1
where   t1.rn > 1
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e761/2/1)